# Merge Sort in reverse

Tags: python

i want to sort the array in descending order using mergeSort

this is the code for my MergeSort implementation in ascending order

```
def MergeSort(B):
        if len(B) <= 1: 
            return 
        mid = len(B)//2
        half1 = B[:mid]
        half2 = B[mid:]
        reverseSort(half1)
        reverseSort(half2)
        merge(half1,half2,B)
    def merge(half1, half2, B):
        i=0; j1=0; j2=0
        while j1<len(half1) and j2<len(half2):
            if half1[j1] < half2[j2]:
                B[i] = half1[j1]
                j1 += 1; i += 1
            else:
                B[i] = half2[j2]
                j2 += 1; i += 1
        while j1 > len(half1):
            B[i] = half1[j1]
            j1 += 1; i += 1
        while j2 > len(half2):
            B[i] = half2[j2]
            j2 += 1; i += 1
```

i have tried changing the following if statement to this
if half1[j1] < half2[j2]:

but the output is incorrect

essentially i want the following

```
B=["cat", "ca", "can", "cat", "cat"]
MergeSortReverse(B)
print(B) #["cat","cat","cat","can","ca"]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def merge_sort_descending(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        mid = len(arr) // 2
        left = arr[:mid]
        right = arr[mid:]
        merge_sort_descending(left)
        merge_sort_descending(right)
        i = j = k = 0
        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if left[i] > right[j]:
                arr[k] = left[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                arr[k] = right[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1
        while i < len(left):
            arr[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
        while j < len(right):
            arr[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
```

```
B=["cat", "ca", "can", "cat", "cat"]
['cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'can', 'ca']
```